# Should I use plural noun after ''both'' in the sentence below?

Tags: grammatical-number

Set the Max depth parameter of both the Reflection and Refraction roll-out to 10.

I am not sure whether *roll-out* should be plural or not in this particular case.

Comment: More detail is needed. First, How are we to understand "roll-out"? Second, is there one roll-out involving reflection and refraction or is there one roll-out for each?

Comment: Roll-out is a drop-down menu, and there are two roll-outs - one for refraction and one for reflection.

Comment: Yes, this involves some level of deletion, and a simplistic answer may be flawed. However, I'd model on _Set the brightness level of both the red and green bulbs at high._ Though I couldn't flaw _levels_ here either.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have answered your own question. "... of both the Reflection and Refraction roll-outs to 10"

The emphatic and unnecessary "Both" is troublesome here. It invites us to understand "... both the Reflection and the Refraction roll-out to 10".

If you had three roll-outs the problem would not arise. "Set the ... of the Reflection, Refraction, and Diffraction roll-outs to 10". To use the singular would suggest that the three variables have one common roll-out rather than one each.