# Should the noun that follows 'both' be singular or plural?

Tags: grammaticality

Should the noun that follows both be singular or plural?
Which of the following is/are correct?

1. I tested both inverting and non-inverting configuration.
2. I tested both inverting and non-inverting configurations.
3. I tested both the inverting and non-inverting configurations.
4. I tested both the inverting and non-inverting configuration.
5. I tested both the inverting and the non-inverting configurations.
6. I tested both the inverting and the non-inverting configuration.

Comment: 1 and 4 don't work.

Comment: @Hot Licks 6. would?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use plural noun after ''both'' in the sentence below?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/544579/should-i-use-plural-noun-after-both-in-the-sentence-below)

Answer (score 0):

Number 2. is what you need. You speak about at least 2 configurations (one inverting and one non-inverting). Since the sentence refers to configurations in general you do not need ***the***. If there would be a description of the configurations that would particularise them, then your sentence would be

> I tested both the inverting and non-inverting configurations *of which we spoke yesterday*.

Comment: Thank you! In this sentence, "I tested both the inverting and non-inverting configurations of which we spoke yesterday.", the definite article applies to both words, correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The less repetitions, the better.

Comment: Why only number 2? What if OP wishes to add the information that there were only two configurations under test ('of which we spoke yesterday' being not part of the question)? 'Both' doesn't mandate plural coordinated NPs (He saw both the boy and the girl) and acceptability with deletions is tricky. A duplicate I believe, but ELU expects answers to demanding questions to be backed by supporting references.

Comment: The only error in any of the sentences is the lack of plural _-s_ on _configurations_. The articles come and go, and don't affect grammaticality in this sentence. Any configuration of _the_'s is grammatical in this sentence. Oh, and to answer what the OP thinks is the question, _both_ means "all two", so plural is required, since 2 is not 1.

Comment: Something sounds wrong to me. Whether you include "the" or not, you are referring to a specific, singular configuration. Try this: "I drove the first and last car, so I drove a total of two cars."  That sentence is an elision of "I drove the first car and I drove the last car, so I drove a total of two cars." I'd argue that leaving out one "configuration" in the sentence does not mean the remaining one becomes plural. That's a grammatical shift that doesn't happen in shortened sentences, as far as I know. I'll look for an authoritative reference for that.